# Want to create drop down menu in my existing main menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am tired to create drop down menu in my existing main menu of website. I have tried many times but no result sometimes I get menu inline sometimes everything disturbed.

HTML code :

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('home')?>">Best Forex Broker</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('toprated')?>">Top Rated Brokers</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="<?=MakeUrl('coupons')?>"> Forex Bonus</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('articles')?>">Articles & Tutorials</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('affiliates')?>">Affiliate Programs</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="<?=MakeUrl('feeds')?>"><img src="<?=$site_folder?>/images/rss.png" alt="RSS" /></a>
</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

and CSS code:

```css
div.mainmenu { background: url('images/body-bg.gif') 0px -50px repeat-x; }
div.mainmenu div.center { background: url('images/body-bg.gif') 0px -50px repeat-x; border-bottom-color: #007399; border-left: none; border-right: none; }
ul.mainmenu { height: 28px; padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px; background: url('images/body-bg.gif') 0px -50px repeat-x; }
ul.mainmenu li { float: left; padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px; margin: 0px;  background: url('images/mainmenu-sep2.gif') left repeat-y; font-size: 15px; }
ul.mainmenu li a { color: #fff;  }
ul.mainmenu li a:hover { color: #e0f0ff; }
ul.mainmenu img { width: 20px; height: 20px; vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px 0px -2px 0px; }
```

I am waiting for anybody to help me . Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes I get menu inline sometimes everything disturbed?

Comment: Pls post a fiddle with your html and CSS for us to be able to help you better and probably faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you may do something like below. Add a class `.dropdown` to the 2dn level menu and hide it to begin with. Then, on `li:hover` display it. You need to apply positions to your main menu and dropdown menu as I did in the CSS. Feel free to style your dropdown the way you like. Take a look.

```css
ul.mainmenu { position: relative; height: 28px; padding: 4px 0px 5px 0px; }
ul.mainmenu li { list-style-type: none; float: left; padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px; margin: 0px; font-size: 15px; }
ul.mainmenu li a { color: #000;  }
ul.mainmenu li a:hover { color: #e0f0ff; }
ul.dropdown { position: absolute; overflow: hidden; top: 24px; margin: 0; display: none; background: #ccc; padding: 0; max-width: 100px; }
ul.mainmenu li:hover .dropdown, .dropdown:hover { display: block; }
```

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('home')?>">Best Forex Broker</a></li>
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('toprated')?>">Top Rated Brokers</a></li>
<li>
    <a href="<?=MakeUrl('coupons')?>"> Forex Bonus</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">drop1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">drop2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">drop3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="<?=MakeUrl('articles')?>">Articles & Tutorials</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello LShetty, thanks for your help. But when drop down menu goes to straight I mean horizontal , I want it drop vertical . As you can see when I move to cursor on link ( Forex Bonus ) it first it drops then goes horizontal . I want it vertical. Hope you will help in this too...

Comment: Sure, you just need to set width or max width to the dropdown. Edited my answer. If it helped, accept the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Waw. It is working now :)  Thanks you very v ery much your nice help.

Comment: And I want to give you vote but it is not allowing me,, website ask me for 15 reputation to give a vote .. lol